# django - circular import problem when executing a command

Tags: python, django, import, circular-reference

I'm developing a django application. Modules of importance to my problem are given below:

**globals.py** --> contains constants that are used throughout the application. `SITE_NAME` and `SITE_DOMAIN` are two of those and are used to fill some strings. Here is how I define them:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
...
SITE_DOMAIN = Site.objects.get_current().domain
SITE_NAME = Site.objects.get_current().name
```

**models.py** --> models live inside this module. imports some constants from globals.py

**some_command.py** --> a command that imports some constants from globals also.

when executed, the command imports a constant from **globals.py** and runs into a circular import problem: inside **globals.py**, **get_current()** from **sites** app is called, and **sites** app in turn imports **models.py** which has imports from **globals.py** as well.

**EDIT:**

The application runs flawlessly, without encountering this circular import issue. Importing **globals.py** from shell brings no problems. Even the command can be executed from the shell without calling **manage.py**.

So why does **manage.py some_command** fail due to a circular import?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason you need to store SITE_DOMAIN and SITE_NAME in globals.py?  These are already available directly from the sites framework.

According to [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/?from=olddocs#caching-the-current-site-object), the site object is cached the first time you access it, so importing it and using it there directly doesn't hurt.

Comment: Some string constants in the globals.py use them, such as this imaginary one: WELCOME_STRING = 'Welcome to' % SITE_NAME

Comment: Lol, welcome string constant. Do you also write some of your views in globals.py? 
http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: @drozzy "globals.py" is just a container for strings that are translated. It is no more "global" than, say, settings.py. Do not prejudge by its name ;)